# Firefox 17.0.1 ignoring font-weight

Tags: html, css, firefox, html-table

http://iamsinc.com/blog/new-producer-bonus/

For some reason Firefox 17.0.1 on my Windows 7 machine is ignoring the font-weight of the td elements. It should be normal. This works fine in Chrome, IE 7 8, & 9, but not in FF. I have also tested it on an XP machine running 17.0.1 and it works fine. The font-weight should be normal, not bold. In the second box down ($300k level), the font-weight is showing up as bold on Win 7 FF 17.0.1 which pushes the pictures outside of the box.

I have even tried reducing the font-weight waaay down and it has not effect on the problematic FF browser

Does anybody have a solution or even a work-around? I hate to make the pictures all smaller just to work around this.

Comment: Did you check if the browser had default overrides set?

Comment: ff18 on win7 shows font-weight:normal

Comment: The problem is not reproducible. There is no reason to think that Firefox is “ignoring the font-weight”, since the default is `normal`, and you are saying that you see bold font. There are 51 markup errors in your HTML, and the CSS is complicated (and has about 228 errors), so you should first fix the obvious errors before addressing this mystery.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe is your browser cache, try to clean it. I have Windows 7 and Firefox 17.0.1 and font-weight is normal.

Comment: I appreciate you answering. That's initially what I thought it was too, but all over my other changes are coming through. I even used private browsing to make sure the cache was clear. I tried it from another Win 7 pc and had the same issue. Here's a screenshot of it: http://imgur.com/cPUhI

Comment: If is not your browser cache, could be one of the fonts. I don't have any Helvetica, so in my case is using Arial and this is what it looks like on Firefox

http://img839.imageshack.us/img839/2062/iamsinccomblognewproduc.jpg

Go to your style.css file line 317 and try removing one or both Helvetica fonts and see what happens.

This is what you actually have:

body, input, textarea {
    color: #373737;
    font: 15px "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
    line-height: 1.625;
}

Answer (score 1):

Now add This rule in your css

```
.npbbox td {
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**The one reason could be** that some **other rule is making font-weight:normal**

Just try using inline style with !important... If it will work then it means that some other rule have high priority...

Check firebug to find it